# How to match URL path using Google RE2 regex

Tags: regex, google-cloud-platform, re2, google-logging

Google Cloud Platform lets you create label logs using the [RE2 regex engine](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

How can I create a regex that matches the path in the URL?

Examples matches:

```
https://example.com/awesome                  --> "awesome"
https://example.com/awesome/path             --> "awesome/path"
https://example.com/awesome/path/            --> "awesome/path"
https://example.com/awesome/path?arg1=123    --> "awesome/path"
```

Details:

- The domain and protocol are constant, it can be assumed to be `https://example.com` here.
- If there are multiple directories, they should be matched too, including the `/` in between.
- Trailing `/` should NOT be matched.
- Queries, e.g. `?arg1=123&arg2=456` should NOT be matched.
- It can be assumed that directory names will only contain alphanumeric characters `a-zA-Z0-9`, dashes `-` and underscores `_`.

Note that [Google RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) is different than [PCRE2](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the syntax isn't 100% clear what is supported and what isn't. Assuming (NOT SUPPORTED) VIM means it is supported but not on vim, I'd start with a negative look behind for the beginning of the url that you don't care about

```
(?<=https:\/\/example\.com\/)
```

Then you want alphanumeric characters `[\w\-]+` followed by non trailing `/` so I'd add a lookahead to verify that there are alphanumeric characters after the `/` with `(?=\/\w+)\/`

The complete regex

```
(?<=https:\/\/example\.com\/)([\w\-]+((?=\/\w+)\/|\b))+
```

Comment: I tested this here and it works: https://regex101.com/r/pL7anj/1
But Google Log metric creation interface still complains that `Must contain exactly one regex group ()`. Is it even possible to accomplish this with a single group?

Comment: @osolmaz do you need regex? I feel like some string manipulation would be an alternative

Comment: RE2 regexes with only 1 regex groups are the only option offered in log metric labels. See https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/labels section that contains "Regular Expression:"

Do you know if there is any other way to extract the path?